# Minecraft Plugin Order

Tags: java, minecraft

I have this code, and I wanted the Player Join Message to go first, but it is going last the order I want is: **Join Message > Spaces > Messages**

```
package me.DevinMC.Joined;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class JoinClass extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getLogger().info("Joined Activated");
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Listener(){
            @EventHandler
            public void onChat(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
                String player = e.getPlayer().getName();
                Player plr = e.getPlayer();
                ChatColor WHITE = ChatColor.WHITE;
                ChatColor GRAY = ChatColor.GRAY;
                String[] messages = {" Welcome to Devin's server", " All the plugins that Devin has made is in the server", " Enjoy :)"};
                plr.sendMessage("                                                                      ");
                plr.sendMessage("                                                                      ");
                for (int msg = 0; msg < messages.length; msg++){
                    plr.sendMessage(ChatColor.BOLD.toString() + ChatColor.BLUE + messages[msg]);
                }
                e.setJoinMessage(" " + WHITE + player + GRAY + " has joined the game");
            }
        },this);
    }
    public void onDisable() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
```

This will force the event to handle before anything else not listed as highest.

http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference

Comment: hm, I changed it and it still seems to go in the incorrect order.

Comment: If you want yours to replace the default, make sure you cancel the event when you are done so nothing else can work it.